# SpringBoot can't scan Controller and get the URL mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, url-mapping

I just wrote a Springboot application as a testing Webserver which origins from spring.io.
It packaged initially in "jar", changed it to "war" file.
And get the application class code as below:

```
package com.ronzhong;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner.Mode;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.ronzhong.libraryManagement"})
public class LibraryManagementApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        application.application().setBannerMode(Mode.OFF);
        return application.sources(SpringApplicationBuilder.class);
    }

    protected WebApplicationContext run(SpringApplication application) {
        return (WebApplicationContext) application.run();
    }

//  public static void main(String[] args) {
//  SpringApplication.run(LibraryManagementApplication.class, args);
//}
}
```

and the controller is :

```
package com.ronzhong.libraryManagement;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CounterController {
    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @PostMapping
    public boolean add(@RequestBody Book book){
        return bookService.add(book);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/books", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Book[] get(){
        return bookService.getBooks();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Book findOne(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        return bookService.findById(id);
    }

}
```

And I also checked the 
"Dynamic Web Module" in the project facets.
Finally, I got these logs when launch tomcat server with this war file generated.

```
INFO: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
2018-11-28 10:43:31.925  INFO 14888 --- [           main] c.ronzhong.LibraryManagementApplication  : Starting LibraryManagementApplication on ronzhongmachine with PID 14888 (C:\Users\ronzhong\workspace_testserver\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\library-Management\WEB-INF\classes started by ronzhong in C:\tools_installers\eclipse-jee-2018-09-win32-x86_64\eclipse)
2018-11-28 10:43:32.002  INFO 14888 --- [           main] c.ronzhong.LibraryManagementApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-28 10:43:33.910  INFO 14888 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/library-Management]      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-11-28 10:43:33.911  INFO 14888 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1604 ms
2018-11-28 10:43:34.362  INFO 14888 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-28 10:43:34.704  INFO 14888 --- [           main] c.ronzhong.LibraryManagementApplication  : Started LibraryManagementApplication in 5.958 seconds (JVM running for 36.407)
2018-11-28 10:43:34.955  INFO 14888 --- [           main] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol     : Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
2018-11-28 10:43:34.968  INFO 14888 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina     : Server startup in 28177 ms
```

There're no mappings info in the logs.
And if I request with http://localhost:8080/api/books, it will get 404 error.
But the logs hasn't change even a little.
So I googled the potential causes, and excluded those causes temporarily:

1. **springboot application does not scan the package which controller locates?**
   I moved springboot application class to the uplevel package, and also specified what kind of package it should scan.
   While you see, it doesn't work.
2. **the annotation issue?**
   Some people say we should use @RestController annotation instead of @Controller, better add the @ResponseBody, while I did.
   it does't work, either.
3. **the deployment issue?**
   don't know, I did changed the build path of this project, which generated  jar file and war file normally, but webapp folder is empty, since I don't have any static resource, I think it's fine, right?

Anyone can help me? very appreciate for your answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: This shouldn't matter, but `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` are annotations that apply to configuration classes, not controllers. They're not needed because `@SpringBootApplication` includes them both. `@Component` is also not needed with `@Controller` or `@RestController`.

Comment: @chrylis, you're right. I just tried to see whether it will have some change with those annotations. I will remove them in case some confusions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs, I can see that your war file name is library-Management, whichh means its deloyed under this folder, as logs states. So you should check http://localhost:8080/library-Management/api/books instead.

You get 404 from Tomcat, it doesnt hit your app at all, this is ehy you dont see any logs.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that.I have to say that's part of cause, while seems not the root cause. After compared with the normal logs, I find it's still missing some FilterRegistrationBeans in the logs. And it still doesn't work in this project. But yes, I just copy the code into another project, it runs well. Thank you so much. If I can't find the anwser in the following days, I will mark your answer as the solution. Again, very appreciate for your answer.